# How do I stop uisearch from searching instantaneously?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uisearchbar

I'm searching using a uisearchbar, a tableview and a JSON web service using the following code. The current problem is that although the app is searching and presenting the data in the tableview it's searching after every text did change occurs in the search bar. I would like it to only search after the user touches the Search button. It's seems to get stuck at the moment while it queries the web with every change in the uisearch text field.

here's how I'm searching:

```
-(void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText
{

    NSString *searchQuery = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://api.****/%@",searchText];

    NSString *jsonString = [NSString
                            stringWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:searchQuery]
                            encoding:NSStringEncodingConversionAllowLossy|NSUTF8StringEncoding
                            error:nil];

    NSMutableArray *itemsTMP = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    SBJSON *parser = [[SBJSON alloc] init];
    NSDictionary *results = [parser objectWithString:jsonString error:nil];

    itemsTMP = [results objectForKey:@"results"];

    //   [self setDisplayItems:[results objectForKey:@"results"]];

    [self setAllItems:[itemsTMP copy]];
    self.displayItems = [itemsTMP copy];

    int a =   [displayItems count];
    NSString *countString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"results %d",a];
    countLabel.text = countString;

    [self.tableView reloadData];


}
```

I was thinking perhaps the code should be moved to

```
-(void) searchBarSearchButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)aSearchBar {

    [self.searchBar resignFirstResponder];

    return;
    // searchBar resigns after search clicked

}
```

but wasn't sure how to add the `:(NSString *)searchText` to this method

thanks for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just convert the `textDidChange` code to `searchBarSearchButtonClicked` method which solves your problem.

```
-(void) searchBarSearchButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)aSearchBar {

    [self.searchBar resignFirstResponder];

    NSString *searchQuery = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://api.****/%@",aSearchBar.text];

    NSString *jsonString = [NSString
                            stringWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:searchQuery]
                            encoding:NSStringEncodingConversionAllowLossy|NSUTF8StringEncoding
                            error:nil];

    NSMutableArray *itemsTMP = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    SBJSON *parser = [[SBJSON alloc] init];
    NSDictionary *results = [parser objectWithString:jsonString error:nil];

    itemsTMP = [results objectForKey:@"results"];

    //   [self setDisplayItems:[results objectForKey:@"results"]];

    [self setAllItems:[itemsTMP copy]];
    self.displayItems = [itemsTMP copy];

    int a =   [displayItems count];
    NSString *countString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"results %d",a];
    countLabel.text = countString;

    [self.tableView reloadData];

    return;
    // searchBar resigns after search clicked

}
```

Comment: thanks! that worked. i put the NSString *searchQuery; in the .h and then kept the searchQuery = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://api.****/%@",searchText]; in the textDidChange method and everything else in searchBarSearchButtonClicked

Comment: Plz chk my updated answer, I append the searchbar text to the searchQuery string. So no need of declaring the searchQuery string in .h file. If u declare it in .h file not creates problem, but if u want it locally, then no need of doing this.